# How does one find and replace text in all open files with gedit?

Tags: editors, text-processing, gedit

How does one find and replace text **in all open files** with [gedit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gedit)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not possible with a stock gedit; there's an open [ubuntu brainstorm idea](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/3933/) for adding the ability. However, there are plugins that add it, such as [advanced-find](http://code.google.com/p/advanced-find/). If you install that, one of the sections on the "Advanced Find/Replace" dialog is "Scope"; choose "All Opened Documents":

[image: Screenshot of the Advanced Find/Replace dialog]

Answer (score 2):

Generally people who want to do this write an ed script and run it against all the files. E.g.:

```
*s/ThrityLimit/ThirtyLimit/
w
q
```

And then run it like this

```
find . -name '*.c' -exec "ed <edscript"
```

You can also use an `ex` script which allows you to use all the : commands from `vi`. It's the same binary as `vi` just called using the command `ex` to start without the gui.

Comment: or with GNU sed: `sed -i -e 's/ThrityLimit/ThirtyLimit/g' *.c`. Or `perl -i -pe 's/ThrityLimit/ThirtyLimit/g' *.c`. With zsh or bash 4, you can traverse subdirectories with `**/*.c`.

Comment: "How does one find and replace text in all open files" indicates that the  user already has selected which files to apply the edit to. This answer does not address that aspect of the question nor does it address the "with gedit" component.